# Update Facebook Status message using an Atmega16 microcontroller

Tags: microcontroller

How can I access Facebook and post a status message using an Atmega16 microcontroller ?
Or what all things I should know for doing this?

Comment: I suppose you could start by looking into using and Arduino [Ethernet Shield](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/9026). Also, most of the tutorials available online are a few years old and I believe both Twitter and Facebook have changed the way they receive updates.

Comment: @GarrettFogerlie: I don't want to use Arduino. Can I use the same methods (if) they have mentioned for Arduino?

Comment: Do you know where to start if you would write a PC program to do this, non-browser based?

Comment: Updating the facebook status is more complicated than you think. Unless facebook enables you to do updates without any kind of security (SSL/TLS) then it might not be that bad. But running SSL on ATMega16 will provide to be a challenge or impossible due to the time it takes to process the keys and the timeout in the protocol. I suggest you take jippie's advice, write a pc program to do it. Then translate that same communication scheme to whatever microcontroller you will use.

Comment: @Inquisitive I believe you can. The Arduino just uses a higher level framework (to make it easier for beginners.) You can use Arduino add-on's with an Atmega16. You just need to work a bit more on the software.

Comment: you would most likely need a proxy service for facebook, like what SuperTweet is for Twitter...

Comment: Is there any reason you've chosen a ATmega16? Atmel has a reference [HTTPS/SSL implementation](http://www.atmel.com/Images/doc32111.pdf) for some of their AVR32 devices.

Comment: @FakeName: I have worked with only ATmega16.

Comment: @Inquisitive - Then get ready to branch out. The ATmega16 is woefully underpowered for SSL.

Comment: @FakeName: Which Microcontroller would you recommend?

Comment: @Inquisitive as FakeName mentioned, working with a AVR32 would probably be a good start. Personally I would recommend using a [ARM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ARM_architecture) based processor.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is half software, half hardware question.

From the hardware side, you'll need a way to get the ATMega connected to some Ethernet so it can connect to the Internet. There is no native support for Ethernet on an ATmega16, so you'll need to use a supporting IC that will do the Ethernet for you. These supporting chips usually communicate to another processor (your ATMega, in this case), over a simple serial link, such as SPI or I2C. As Garrett Fogerlie mentioned, you can take a look at some of the Arduino shields. You don't have to use an Arduino - just look at how the circuit works.

The Arduino Ethernet shield uses a supporting IC that communicates over the SPI bus. So first, you should figure out how to get SPI working on you ATMega. After that, this question starts to tread into software territory quite quickly. As others have mentioned, the software side of this is likely less than trivial. I don't know anything about communicating with Facebook, so I'll stop here.

Comment: Good explanation. His best bet would probably be to use the Atmega to communicate with a server, then that server will connect to Facebook.

Answer (score 4):

There are four ways to do it. First is tethered to a computer (essentially using the microcontroller as a glorified sensor) with the computer running software to actually do the status updating. The second is the same, but with a router or bluetooth+cellphone other embedded computer instead (DDWRT or Openwrt is always a good starting point).

The third is semi-standalone. You use your atmega16 with a network connection (an ethernet shield or wifi shield, w5100 or ENC28J60, or serial to ethernet or serial to wifi modules, gsm modems, etc) talking to a php web host you run, that actually talks to the facebook api.

The fourth is that you do all of this on your atmega16, talking to Facebook's api directly, without needing a computer or router or web host.

These are from easiest to hardest.

For the most part, haven't seen any arduino or similar project that succeeds in complete standalone. Facebook requires OAuth for posting status updates, and running that on a microcontroller isn't easy or feasible or frankly been done. Killed alot of twitter microcontroller projects until Supertweet came out (twitter oauth/microcontroller basic auth proxy)